# Grok Filters for multiple logs of different patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a `input.log` file which contains the following logs

```
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     X-Proxy-ID: 1762099788 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     X-Forwarded-For: 100.0.3.252 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Via: 1.1 100.0.0.1 (Mikrotik HttpProxy) 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:  2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs: Response to "HEAD http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/27512d7b-b987-49de-bd6f-c417e26ca2e3?P1=1502449265&P2=301&P3=2&P4=YY7gZVc8SsdgSjByOKsRU%2b7cRbUIZIVgXp0qiEVn%2blQ%3d": 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     HTTP/1.1 302 Hotspot login required 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Cache-Control: no-cache 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Content-Length: 135 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Content-Type: text/html 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 11:04:27 GMT 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Expires: 0 2017-08-11 16:34
web-proxy,debug userWebLogs:     Location: http://l.openwifi.in/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Ftlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com%2Ffilestreamingservice%2Ffiles%2F27512d7b-b987-49de-bd6f-c417e26ca2e3%3FP1%3D1502449265%26P2%3D301%26P3%3D2%26P4%3DYY7gZVc8SsdgSjByOKsRU%252b7cRbUIZIVgXp0qiEVn%252bl 2017-08-11 16:34
```

and i also have a `logstash.conf` file which contains filter code like this

```
    input {
    file {
        path => "E:/logstash-5.5.1/root/input.log" 
    }
}
filter{
  grok{
    match => { "message"=> "%{WORD:word1}-%{WORD:word2},%{WORD:word3}" }
  }
}
output {
    stdout {}
    file {
        path => "E:/logstash-5.5.1/root/output.log"
        codec => line{format=>"%{message}"}
    }
}
```

I need logs which contains URL's and IP addresses

I need help in writing the Filter `match` code.

Any help will be accepted.

Comment: Perhaps you could add what you are trying to do, by indicating what is the expected result, i.e. what is the data you want extracted.

Comment: To help you, there are a few resources: [the available patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) and [a pattern tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match).

Comment: I need logs which contains URL's and IP addresses

Comment: You should use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) to filter logs with URL and IP adresses, then extract them with multiple grok filters.